# What's the first thing I should try to learn before learning to program?

Tags: javascript

I'm coming from an XHTML/CSS background. I don't know much about JavaScript. Would you recommend learning JavaScript before learning a server programming language?

Comment: One more thing is that I did read a bit about PHP. Is that a good first one to learn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not really. You could try to learn both at the same time. You can have a lot of fun with AJAX, sending data to and from a webserver to dynamically update your page.

A serverside language like PHP is very similar to JavaScript, so you shouldn't have any trouble learning both at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

I think that's a fine idea.  If you really understand XHTML and CSS, then doing some simple event programming via jquery could be really fun.  That said, what you learn won't make learning a server-side platform easier as the way you work in the two environments, and their trappings, are really different.  Still, learning to manipulate the DOM will make your CSS work that much cooler.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways into "programming" as a profession.
The traditional route involves picking courses, and languages, based on some end goal :- "I would like to become a server developer".

The other way will nett you far less certificates. But it amounts to: learn whatever inspires you. Because its inspiration thats the natural learning state. There are no limits to the number of languages, or useful factoids, that can be learn't this way.
Find problems you are inspired to solve. Simple problems at first. And solve them. By programming in *some* language.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest starting from [scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/).

Comment: That's a really helpful contribution. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if you are sarcastic, but I really do think that the Scratch language teaches very useful programming concepts without you having to waste time studying a language syntax or setting up a complicated ecosystem.

Comment: Hahaha, I'm sorry. I looked at your answer in my phone and didn't see the link. I thought you were saying "Start from scratch", figuratively speaking. +1 for you answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are a page designer right now. If you want to switch to a hard-core programming role, I'd recommend a formal programming language to start with, either Java or C#.

Comment: There is no reason for you to switch to "hard-core programming". If you are a webdesigner now, then stick to that. If you can program in JavaScript and PHP, then you are going to be a lot more valuable than if you can do proper languages.

Comment: Sure, screw superior object-oriented programming languages and secure frameworks that they sit on top of. Who needs that when you have PHP. What a ludicrous comment.

Comment: @user68137 I think he's right. I'm not trying to save the world, but rather, just make money and have fun doing it. There seems to be a lot of PHP jobs on monster.com that area over 80k. I don't see too many C# jobs on there for that range. When considering the learning curve differences between the two languages it seems like a no-brainer. I've been looking at Python too now. It seems easy to learn like PHP, but doesn't seem to have all the complaints.